# PhpStorm error when running debugger: SyntaxError: Unexpected token = (on class property)

Tags: phpstorm

```
static UNUSED_TILE = " ";
                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

When I comment out that specific static property, it errs on the next one in the file:

```
class Tile {
  static UNUSED_TILE = " ";
  static HUMAN_MARKER = "X";
  static COMPUTER_MARKER = "O";
```

I have Node 12.4.0. This only happens when running my debugger in PhpStorm 2019.3. `node fileName.js` in terminal runs without issues. Any idea what the the debugger could be doing to still have issue?

```
//package.json
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^25.2.3",
    "jest-cli": "^25.2.3"
  }
```

Debugger settings

[image: Node debugger]

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshots show that you have node 8.10.0 used as node.js interpreter; this node.js version doesn't support class properties. According to [this table](https://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--instance-class-fields), they are supported since Node.js 12.x. If you have the appropriate version installed (you wrote that you have Node 12.4.0), please make sure to select it as a **Node interpreter:** in your run configuration